# Can the function argument to `call/cc` equivalently either invoke the continuation or return without invoking the continuation?

Tags: scheme, continuations, continuation-passing, callcc

The Scheme Programming Language says

> Scheme allows the continuation of any expression to be captured with the procedure `call/cc`. `call/cc`
>   must be passed a procedure `p` of one argument. `call/cc` constructs a concrete representation of the current
>   continuation and passes it to `p`. The continuation itself is represented by a procedure `k`. Each time `k` is applied
>   to a value, it returns the value to the continuation of the `call/cc` application. This value becomes, in
>   essence, the value of the application of `call/cc`.
>   If `p` returns without invoking `k`, the value returned by the procedure becomes the value of the application of
>   `call/cc`.

Are the two following ways of defining `p` equivalent, as far as being called by `call/cc` is concerned:

- `p` returns without invoking `k`,
- `p`   calls `k` with its otherwise return value?

I am not sure how `call/cc` is defined. 
Does `call/cc` ever directly call the continuation `k`, besides indirectly via `p` calling `k`?

Is it perfectly fine that both `call/cc` and `p` don't invoke continuation `k`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `(call/cc (lambda (k) 1)) <=> (call/cc (lambda (k) (k 1)))`. You can prove this by using the continuation passing style transform.

The key part is the CPS form of `call/cc` is `(lambda (k) (lambda (f) ((f k) k)))`. And the CPS forms of the two functions are `(lambda (c) (lambda (k) (c 1)))` and `(lambda (c) (lambda (k) (k 1)))`. Substitute and simplify and both result in `(lambda (k) (k 1))`.

I greatly prefer delimited continuations as they have:

```
(reset (1 + (shift (lambda (f) f)))) <=> (lambda (v) (+ 1 v))
```

This can also be proved algebraically.

Comment: Thanks. How do you   prove `(call/cc (lambda (k) 1)) <=> (call/cc (lambda (k) (k 1)))` by using the continuation passing style transform?

Answer (score 1):

To work out the details of the follow up question we can use the code scheme-cps-convert.rkt from http://matt.might.net/articles/cps-conversion/

```
> (T-c '(call/cc (λ (k) 1)) 'halt)
'((λ (f cc) (f (λ (x _) (cc x)) cc)) (λ (k $k2873) ($k2873 1)) halt)
> (T-c '(call/cc (λ (k) (k 1))) 'halt)
'((λ (f cc) (f (λ (x _) (cc x)) cc)) (λ (k $k2940) (k 1 $k2940)) halt)
```

reducing the first expression:

```
  ((λ (f cc) (f (λ (x _) (cc x)) cc)) (λ (k $k2873) ($k2873 1)) halt)
= ((λ (k $k2873) ($k2873 1)) (λ (x _) (halt x)) halt)
= (halt 1)
```

and the second

```
  ((λ (f cc) (f (λ (x _) (cc x)) cc)) (λ (k $k2940) (k 1 $k2940)) halt)
= ((λ (k $k2940) (k 1 $k2940)) (λ (x _) (halt x)) halt)
= ((λ (x _) (halt x)) 1 halt)
= (halt 1)
```

proves they are equal, so using k or not using k in that position makes no difference.